# difference from default configuration in .deb

Tags: ubuntu, debian, configuration, package-management, system-state

To my great surprise I have not found an easy way to view the difference between locally altered configuration files in /etc from the defaults supplied in .deb for particular package.

Some day in future when debian/ubuntu will finally migrate to stateless /etc pushed by systemd it'll be trivial but now the closest I could find is 'debsums -ce'. Unfortunately it only reports the list of files, not an actual diff.

This is obviously tracked because on upgrade dpkg always asks what to do with altered configuration but how to get the set of diffs without upgrading?

Comment: Are you sure that dpkg is tracking the diffs for the files and not just their checksums?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear - yes, it does tracking through checksums, but it's capable of displaying diff between package-supplied and locally-modified configs for those with different checksums. What I'd like is exactly this functionality.